# Problem connecting to an Oracle database through Server Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, oracle10g

Here is the setup: I run Windows 7, Visual Studio 2008 and need to connect to an Oracle Database. The Oracle software installed is Oracle Database 10g Release 2 (10.2.0.4.0) where I selected 10204_vista_w2k8_x64_production_db.zip. I was ordered to select this driver by a superior (something with backward compatibility). There isn't a Windows 7 version of this, but it can be installed by avoiding the OS check. I used this guide:

[Oracle forum link](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4598642)

It installed without problems. I guess it's just not officially supported by Oracle on Windows 7. But I can't connect to the database through Server Explorer in Visual Studio. It gives this error:

> Attempt to load Oracle Client
>   Libraries threw
>   BadImageFormatException. This problem
>   will occur when running in 64 bit mode
>   with the 32 bit Oracle client
>   components installed.

I was able to make a connection through C# code though. Any suggestions why Server Explorer can't connect?

edit:
I can also connect to the database using Oracle's SQL Plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Visual Studio is a 32 bit process and can't load 64 bit dll-s